# How to express "It doesn’t take much (for something) to do ..."

Tags: expressions

> 1 : Il suffit de **pas** grand-chose pour que ma voiture tombe en panne.

When using this expression, do you need to omit « ne », only keeping « pas », as shown above?

I cannot help but feel that including « ne » in this specific expression does not make sense.

> 2 : Il **ne** suffit de **pas** grand-chose pour que ma voiture tombe en panne.
>
> 3 : Il **ne** suffit **pas** de grand-chose pour que ma voiture tombe en panne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

**2) is broken**

**3) makes sense and is fine**

---

Long version:

1) Dropping the *ne* is colloquial like with all negative sentences, e.g.

> *Je ne viens pas* → Written French, formal
>
> *Je viens pas* → Spoken French, colloquial

Your first sentence is close to such colloquial *ne* dropping:

> Il suffit de pas grand-chose pour que ma voiture tombe en panne.
>
> [pas grand chose] [suffit] [pour que ma voiture tombe en panne]
>
> [almost nothing] [is sufficient] [for my car to break down]

but the real *ne* dropping is present with the colloquial version:

> Il suffit pas de grand-chose pour que ma voiture tombe en panne.

2) *grand-chose*, technically *grande chose*, means "a big thing". However, it is (almost) always used in negative context in modern French.

The [tlfi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chose) says about *grand-chose*:

> *c) Grand-chose [Toujours dans un énoncé négatif, à négation composée, et immédiatement précédé de pas, plus ou jamais] De très peu d'importance, presque rien, pas beaucoup.*

The lack of final *-e* in *grand* is due to the fact the expression *grand-chose*, which used to be written *grand'chose* until a 1932 Académie française décision, was created when *grand/grant* was used for both the masculine and the feminine form.

Reference: [Les locutions grand monde et grand-chose : Un cas de grammaticalisation ? Jacqueline Bacha, Persée](http://www.persee.fr/doc/igram_0222-9838_2007_num_113_1_3881)

The tlfi states *grand-chose* immediately follows *pas, plus, or jamais* but in fact, *de* definitely can appear in between, e.g.

> — Ils savent, mon frère, ce que je vous ai dit, qui **ne** guérit **pas de grand-chose**, et toute l'excellence de leur art consiste en un pompeux galimatias, en un spécieux babil, qui vous donne des mots pour des raisons, et des promesses pour des effets.

Molière, Le malade imaginaire.

3) The second sentence is breaking the rule that says *ne* and *pas* immediately surround a conjugated verb (*ne suffit pas*):

> Il <s>ne suffit de pas</s> grand-chose pour que ma voiture tombe en panne.

4) The third sentence is the written French / formal way to express the first one.

> Il ne suffit pas de grand-chose pour que ma voiture tombe en panne.

Because *grand-chose* is never used positively, it can't be parsed this way:

> [grand chose] [ne suffit pas] [pour que ma voiture tombe en panne]
>
> [a big thing] [is not sufficient] [for my car to break down]

which would mean your car is unbreakable but, just like your first sentence:

> [pas grand chose] [suffit] [pour que ma voiture tombe en panne]
>
> [almost nothing] [is sufficient] [for my car to break down]

If we go back to Molière's phrase, the formal version is:

> Ce que je vous ai dit ne guérit pas de grand chose.

The less formal one would have been:

> Ce que je vous ai dit guérit de pas grand chose.

---

Digging a little more to reply to critics:

Googling "***Il ne suffit pas de beaucoup***" which is semantically very similar to "***Il ne suffit pas de grand-chose***" leads to enough hits to allow an analysis.

Interestingly, when *beaucoup* is followed by a verb, the meaning is mostly  "*beaucoup* is not enough" but there are also some cases where the meaning is the opposite "*beaucoup* is not required". On the other hand, when *beaucoup* ends the clause or is followed by a noun, the meaning is **always** (as far as my analysis is concerned) the second one, i.e. "*beaucoup* is not necessary".

- *Beaucoup* + verb: (*beaucoup* is not enough)

> *Rappelons qu'il ne suffit pas de beaucoup lire en s'imprégnant des différents rituels mis à notre disposition pour être initié.* (reading a lot is not enough)
>
> *Mais il ne suffit pas de beaucoup travailler pour réussir un spectacle.* (a lot of work is not enough to succeed)
>
> *Il ne suffit pas de beaucoup parler mais il faut également peser sur l'échiquier national.* (speaking a lot is not enough)
>
> *Il ne suffit pas de beaucoup s'entraîner, il faut aussi et surtout comprendre ce que l'on fait et pourquoi* (training a lot is not enough)

- *Beaucoup* + verb: (*beaucoup* is not necessary)

> *Il ne suffit pas de beaucoup gagner pour donner.* (no need to make a lot of money to donate)
>
> *Il ne suffit pas de beaucoup s'éloigner de la capitale pour être dépaysé par la brousse et les villages croisés* (no need to move off a lot from the capital to reach the exotic bush and villages)

- *Beaucoup* ending a clause: (*beaucoup* is not necessary), always

> *Il ne suffit pas de beaucoup, 50 euros par mois peut être un très bon début.* (No need for a lot, €50 is enough for a starter)
>
> *Parfois, il ne suffit pas de beaucoup, un régime de retraite permettant de jouir de la vie pour le reste de ses jours* (same as the above)
>
> *De là à passer à l'acte, il ne suffit pas de beaucoup.* (A small event might be enough for someone to commit the act)

- *Beaucoup* + noun: (*beaucoup* is not necessary), always

> *Et il ne suffit pas de beaucoup de temps pour se retrouver dans une épaisse forêt tropicale avec des arbres aux tronc et aux racines impressionnantes.* (a few time is enough to reach the forest)
>
> *Il ne suffit pas de beaucoup de moyens pour rendre les enfants heureux* (no need for a lot of resources to make kids happy)
>
> *Il ne suffit pas de beaucoup de temps pour se rendre compte de la différence entre ces deux vélos, c'est d'ailleurs bluffant* (a few time is enough to realize the difference)
>
> *Il ne suffit pas de beaucoup d'eau pour détruire une carte mère* (a small amount of water is enough to destroy a main board).
>
> *Il ne suffit pas de beaucoup d'espace pour créer un petit coin jardin tout à fait charmant* (a small area is sufficient to create a charming garden)

***Grand-chose*** being undoubtedly closer to **[*beaucoup* + noun]** than **[*beaucoup* + verb]**, ***Il ne suffit pas de grand-chose*** pour que ma voiture tombe en panne means "**Some big thing is not necessary** for my car to break down" thus **3) makes sense and is fine**.

Comment: Hi. Is it just me, but the third sentence seems to mean: "**Il faudrait plus que grand-chose** pour que ma voiture tombe en panne." = "My car **rarely** breaks down." So it seems that the meaning is at odds with that of the first sentence that goes: "It doesn't take much for my car to break down." = "My car **easily** breaks down." Merci.

Comment: It's just you ;-) *Grand-chose* technically means "a lot of things/ a big thing" but is never used a positive way so you simply can't say *plus que grand-chose*. *Il ne suffit pas de grand-chose* is equivalent to *il suffit de presque rien* which is also equivalent to what you wrote in your initial sentence *il suffit de pas grand chose*. I would probably use the the conditional here though: *il suffirait de pas grand chose*

Comment: I have the same feeling than @LUNA... Using "grand-chose" in a positive way seems wrong, so "pas grand-chose" should be the whole expression, so in sentence 2, I feel a missing "pas" (where it should be "Il **ne** suffit **pas** de pas grand-chose") but makes the sentence odd, and in sentence 3, I feel a missing "pas" (where it should be "Il ne suffit pas de **pas grand-chose**"... Are you sure about your statement ?

Comment: I agree with LUNA and Random, it does feel like it's saying the opposite of its meaning worded like that. Although [there is a poem named like that](http://www.lespoetes.net/poeme-SOURIRE-10921.html), it's not exactly Voltaire... My opinion is that there is no reason to add "*ne*" in a sentence with "*il suffit*", it's meant to be followed by something that means "not much", and that's what "*pas grand chose*" is.

Comment: On the other hand, I was writing an answer but I realised "*pas grand chose*" is almost always used with "*ne*". I think the expression is colloquial from the start, and there is no correct version (using grand-chose). The literal version of this would be "*il suffit de peu de chose*".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I don't get what makes you believe *il ne suffit pas de grand chose* is incorrect. This is grammatical and usual French. The sentence doesn't say "*il suffit*" but "*il ne suffit pas*".

Comment: I'm not saying it's grammatically incorrect. I'm saying it means the opposite of "*il suffit de pas grand-chose*". If you say "*Il ne suffit pas d'avoir le brevet pour trouver un travail*", it means "having [A] it's not enough", which is quite the opposite of "*il suffit de [A] pour ..*", "all you need is [A] to ...". It's literally the opposite.

Comment: As a French I have to admit that the sentence didn't surprise me at first but when I started really thinking about it it doesn't really make sense. I just think "*Il suffit de pas grand chose*" is colloquial and doesn't exist with "*ne*", maybe I'm wrong. I didn't find convincing counterexamples.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I got your point. Thanks for insisting. That leads me to try to clarify mine. I found Molière instead of Voltaire, albeit with *guérir*, not *suffire*…

Comment: @jlliagre Nice work. I'm not the one who downvoted you, but I still think you're going the wrong way. *Guérir* does not behave like *suffire*. *Il ne guérit pas de beaucoup* and *Il guérit de pas beaucoup* are equivalent, but *Il suffit de pas beaucoup* and *il ne suffit pas de beaucoup* are opposite (allegedly). After thinking about it, I think we're in a sterile debate because "*Il ne suffit pas de [somehting big]*" probably doesn't even exist, so it's pointless to try to agree on what it means. Until proven to the contrary I'll assume it doesn't.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Answer updated with a drop of *énantiosémie* ;-)